# Adding Kendo UI for Angular to ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-angular2

The project I'm working on has been written in ASP.NET MVC using Kendo UI.
I'm working on implementing Angular 4 into the project. We are already using Kendo UI controls, so I decided to go with Kendo UI for Angular components.

The problem I encounter is that current bootstrap/kendo libraries appear to conflict with Kendo UI for Angular libraries. Whenever I try to use kendo-dropddownlist or any other control like datetimepicker, the control generated looks/behaves differently to how it should do [(as seen on kendo site)](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#)

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="currencies"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

The main differences are: focus out doesn't close the list of items, active/hover styles look very bad, the animation looks terrible (the list jumps up before sliding down)
This is just a few of the issue I encounter.

Does anyone has any ideas why this is happening or how I could identify the cause of this? 
Has anyone actually tried implementing Kendo UI for Angular inside ASP.NET MVC app?

System.config.js code:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': '/src/app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',

            '@progress': 'npm:@progress',
            '@telerik': 'npm:@telerik'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                meta: {
                    './*.js': {
                        loader: '/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                    }
                }
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            // Kendo UI for Angular packages
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-inputs': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@telerik/kendo-inputs-common': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-l10n': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@telerik/kendo-draggable': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-intl': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-popup': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-popup-common': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'npm:@progress/kendo-date-math': {
                main: './dist/npm/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
        }
    });
})(this);
```

In my Layout page I'm using Kendo CDN's

```
@Styles.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css")
@Styles.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")
@Styles.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")
@Styles.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")
@Styles.Render("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css") 
@Scripts.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/jquery.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "~4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "~4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "~4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "~4.4.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.4.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.4.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^2.9.3",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.47.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "bootstrap-css-only": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.3",
    "systemjs": "0.20.19",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.54",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using angular 5 in an MVC 5 app without the problems you are describing.  Do you have both Kendo for JQuery and Angular on the same page? Please give specific code examples.

Comment: Yes I do have Kendo UI for JQuery and Kendo UI for Angular on the same page. I added some more code. I'm not sure what else I should add. My html templates are very simple, as I'm just testing stuff. Let me know if I should add some more details.
You said your working with Angular 5. Would you mind providing your package.json code as I was struggling to update it to 5 due to failing dependencies.